# BNHtmlPdfKit Code Not Doing Anything on iOS

Tags: ios, pdf-generation

I am trying to use [BNHtmlPdfKit](https://github.com/brentnycum/BNHtmlPdfKit) to save some HTML as a PDF. Just to see if it works, I'm trying to take a web page and write it to a PDF. I'm unable to get it to work (at all). Below is my code.

First, I include the delegate reference:

```
@interface PPToolsTableViewController () <BNHtmlPdfKitDelegate>
```

Then I do the following:

```
NSString *exportsPath = [[PPHelpers documentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"exports/Exported.pdf"]];

BNHtmlPdfKit *htmlPdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] init];
htmlPdfKit.delegate = self;
[htmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"] toFile:exportsPath];
```

Nothing happens. No errors, and none of the delegate methods fire:

```
- (void) createPdf:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"Create PDF");
}
- (void)htmlPdfKit:(BNHtmlPdfKit *)htmlPdfKit didSavePdfData:(NSData *)data {
  NSLog(@"PDF Save Data");
}
- (void)htmlPdfKit:(BNHtmlPdfKit *)htmlPdfKit didSavePdfFile:(NSString *)file {
  NSLog(@"PDF Save File");
}
- (void)htmlPdfKit:(BNHtmlPdfKit *)htmlPdfKit didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"PDF Error");
}
```

Is anyone familiar with this library able to provide me with a working example? Or perhaps spot what's wrong with what I'm doing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found this little snippet in the documentation which led me to a solution:

> Be sure to retain a reference to the BNHtmlPdfKit object outside the
>   scope of the calling method. Otherwise, no delegate methods will be
>   called...

So making the BNHtmlPdfKit object a `@property` made all the difference:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) BNHtmlPdfKit *htmlPdfKit;
```

...then this worked:

```
NSString *exportsPath = [[PPHelpers documentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"exports/Logbook.pdf"]];

self.htmlPdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] init];
self.htmlPdfKit.delegate = self;

[self.htmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"] toFile:exportsPath];
```

All better now. :)